# Does the "MS Access Database" ODBC driver support multiple users?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, odbc, ado

I'm writing a tool in Excel VBA that will need to write to a simple table on the organization's network. Several people will be using the tool to write to that table, possibly at the same time.

I had hoped to use the ODBC text driver to write to a CSV file to use as the table, but I see that it does not support multiple users.

What about the "MS Access Database" odbc driver? If I use ADO to create and manage that database, will multiple users be able to write to it at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, yes. I run some web based applications using Access as the back end via ODBC and there has never been a problem with concurrency.

Be aware however that the ODBC driver is not IP based, it needs local or network share access to the database file.

Answer (score 1):

Excel VBA can via DAO connect to the Access database file directly and with a maximum of 255 users concurrently.

No need to bother with ODBC.